# finding and replacing 'nan' with a number

Tags: python, numpy, import

I want to replace number 3 instead of all 'nan' in array. this is my code:

```
train= train.replace("nan",int(3))
```

But nothing changes in my array.  Could u please guide me?

Comment: Aside: what does `print(type(train))` return?  Neither lists nor numpy ndarrays have a `replace` method, so I'm not sure why you're not getting an AttributeError.  Is `train` a pandas Series?

Comment: To follow up on @DSM's comment, if `train` were a pandas dataframe or Series, there's a `fillna()` method that handles this sort of situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> import math
>>> train = [10, float('NaN'), 20, float('NaN'), 30]
>>> train = [3 if math.isnan(x) else x for x in train]
>>> train
[10, 3, 20, 3, 30]
```

Answer (score 32):

You can use `np.isnan`:

```
import numpy as np
train = np.array([2, 4, 4, 8, 32, np.NaN, 12, np.NaN]) 
train[np.isnan(train)]=3
train
```

Output:

```
array([  2.,   4.,   4.,   8.,  32.,   3.,  12.,   3.])
```

Answer (score 0):

This code changes all `nan` to `3`:

```
y = np.nan_to_num(x) + np.isnan(x)*3
```

This code changes all `3` to `nan`:

```
y = x*(x!=3) + 0/(x!=3)
```

These methods only work with numpy arrays. Please note that `np.nan_to_num(x)` always changes `nan` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The following works with floats, but could not quickly make it with integers... Terveisin Markus

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2,3,np.nan])
b=np.nan_to_num(a,nan=3)
print(f"a: {a}")
print(f"b: {b}")
```

> a: [ 1.  2.  3. nan]

> b: [1. 2. 3. 3.]